# Vue / Typescript, got Module '"*.vue"' has no exported member

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I want to export several interfaces together with `Component` from `.vue` file.

**Basic.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";

export interface IBasic {
    name :string;
}

/**
 * Simplest container
 */
@Component
export class Basic extends Vue {}
export default Basic;
</script>
```

But when I import it from another `.ts` file, I got:

[image]

What can I do to import the interface successfully?

Comment: Why not move `IBasic` into its own file that could be imported by whatever needs it?

Comment: Although it's doable to put them into a separate file, I'm looking for the possibility to put them together with components. Especially when the interfaces are useless elsewhere.

Comment: Any news on this issue? Is collecting all exports to one default object only way to go for now?

Comment: Looks like vscode + Vetur@0.34.1 already fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and realize that despite of no having errors on my IDE, the error was still thrown so I just **Restart the server** and it works perfectly... I have to do this every time I created a import or export anything with TS.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the `interface` into another TS file

component.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
   
/**
 * Simplest container
 */
@Component
export class Basic extends Vue {}
export default Basic;
</script>
```

interfaces.ts

```
export interface IBasic {
    name :string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [ktsn/vuetype](https://github.com/ktsn/vuetype) which will generate a custom declaration file for every component file, instead of using the default `shims-vue.d.ts` declaration.

Comment: This seems like an actual solution unlike the other answers, but it seems a little heavy. Is there a way to modify the default `shims-vue.d.ts` declaration to accept an arbitrary named export.

Answer (score 1):

If you use WS then try to change Vue service in Settings - TypeScript - Vue to Vue Language Service[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can drop the { } from your import. It’s a default export, so then you write import IBasic from "@/../containers/Basic"

Comment: There is a default export but there is also a named `IBasic` which is presumably what is desired.

Comment: Why is this upvoted. It doesn't answer the question in any way.

Answer (score -1):

Using this Plugin in VS Code solved the Problem for me:
https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/vue-ts-plugin

It is a fork that is actively maintained. I ran `yarn add -D ts-vue-plugin` and added these compiler options to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
compilerOptions: {
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "plugins": [{ "name": "ts-vue-plugin" }]
}
```

My Code (storybook 6 file `button.stories.ts`):

```
import Button, { BUTTON_TYPE } from '@/components/Button.vue';
```

With this both the type import finally works and I can jump to the file (CMD+click) instead of jumping to the `shims-vue.d.ts` like it used to. Good luck!