# How to avoid TS2614 error when importing interfaces from Vue components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

I have defined an interface in my Vue component script section and when I tried to import it in another typescript file this error appears:

> `TS2614: Module '"../pages/categories/alimentation/index.vue"' has no exported member 'BenefitDetails'. Did you mean to use 'import BenefitDetails from "../pages/categories/alimentation/index.vue"' instead`

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

export interface BenefitDetails {
  name: string
  frequency: string
  cost: number
  icon: string
  description: string
}

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  // my props ...

  mounted() {}
}
</script>
```

---

```js
// Error in import below
import { BenefitDetails } from '~/pages/categories/alimentation/index.vue'

export function getBenefitFrequencyColor({ frequency }: BenefitDetails) {
  switch (frequency) {
    case 'Mensal':
      return 'blue'
    default:
      return 'yellow'
  }
}
```

I found a solution to VSCode in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126929/vue-typescript-got-module-vue-has-no-exported-member/56181961) question but I am using WebStorm.

UPDATE: I do not want to move the interface declaration to another file

Comment: Please post the text of your code rather than a screenshot

Comment: in `tsconfig.json`, is `compilerOptions.allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set to `true`? If not, add it and this should fix the problem.

Comment: Only adding this settings to `tsconfig.json` didn't worked. Restarting the IDE with this settings worked, but I also noticed that only restarting the IDE the problem is gone regardless of any changes to `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Restarting webstorm solved it for me.

Comment: I'm at WebStorm 2023 and the problem occurred again although it didn't exist in WebStorm 2021

Answer (score 1):

What IDE version do you use? Can't see any errors when using your code in 2020.3.1 (with the language service enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript**):

[image]

Comment: ```WebStorm 2020.3.1
Build #WS-203.6682.155, built on December 28, 2020
Licensed to Michael Douglas Pacheco Gonçalves Dias
Subscription is active until February 5, 2021.
For educational use only.
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.63 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.8.0-36-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.balloon.shadow.size=0
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.chrisrm.idea.MaterialThemeUI, com.mallowigi, com.markskelton.one-dark-theme, ru.adelf.idea.dotenv, com.vermouthx.idea
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME```

Comment: I dont know if this is relevant but I'm using Nuxt.js

Comment: I just restarted Webstorm and everthing is working again

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring BenefitDetails interface in de dedicated ts file (ie: benefitDetails.model.ts)

Then import the BenefitDetails where needed

Comment: It's a valid solution. But not what I want. I have updated the question with this info